# Python v3 threading and OS context-switching (changed from v2?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, python-multithreading, context-switch

I hit the dead end with python 3 threading. Example script is somehow trivial while its behaviour is different compared to previous python version (tested with python 2.7).
The idea is to start function (`to_time_it()`) which waits a thread (`thread_it()`) to clear some flag. Thread is running continuosly until the very end, and sleep() inside both functions ensure that python must pool flags with `while` statement.

The problem is, python v2(.7 in my case) runs faster, almost deterministicly faster, about (10 + 5) = 15 ms on my HP (win10, Intel i5, 32bit python v2.7) or some older linux pc. Although the same code run OK on python 3.6, something is causing this 10ms delay, **except** if there is some pointless `print` or `sleep(0)` inside certain while loop. Here is the code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time as systime
import timeit
import threading

flag = False
thread_flag = False

counter = 0

AVERAGE = 10

def thread_it():
    global flag
    global thread_flag

    #run thread until thread_flag is not set
    while not thread_flag:
        while flag:
            # (1)
            #print("")
            #systime.sleep(0)
            pass

        #print("!")
        systime.sleep(0.05) # force to_time_it() to wait thread to set flag

        flag = True # return to thread while loop

def to_time_it():
    global flag
    global counter 

    flag = False    # break out of thread while loop 
    #   - > to systime.sleep() after #(1) and than set flag

    # wait thread to set flag (thread is than waiting for new cycle in it's while loop)
    systime.sleep(0.03) 

    while not flag: # wait for flag (approx 20ms)
        # (2)
        #print("")
        #systime.sleep(0)
        pass    # do nothing

    print("OK: %s" %counter) # thread has cleared flag, can start new cycle
    counter += 1


def main():
    global thread_flag
    global flag

    print("Threading while loop test")

    th = threading.Thread(target=thread_it)
    th.start()

    tajm = timeit.timeit(to_time_it, number=AVERAGE) * 1000 / AVERAGE

    systime.sleep(0.7)  #not neccesary, just to see what is happening when printing out data

    # exit/end thread
    thread_flag = True
    flag = False

    print("\n\tAverage time: %.2f ms" % tajm)

    #os._exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The point where this code can run equally fast on both python versions is marked with `# (1)` and `# (2)`. It turns out, that a simple `print("")` or `time.sleep(0)` make some internal change that causes to disapear this delay when running on python 3. Adding any of it to point `#(1)` causes 10ms delay to disapear, and adding anything to point `#(2)` causes the other 5ms to disapear. I don't know why `while something: pass` is treated differently than `while something: time.sleep(0)`. Moving `pass`, `sleep()` or `print()` to external function has no effect.

I assume some changes about python threading module must have occured in v3, causing OS context switch / process or thread priority handling to act differently on newer version. Can anyone test this and confim/explain?

***Note:*** [I already started a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198172/python-v2-7-and-v3-6-behave-differently-but-the-same), but I didn't get any responses. I started a new topic (not comment/edit) because I managed to strip down test script dependencies of pyserial and because I belive this is a more general python issue. Please, redirect me to better place or let me know what are other ways of getting experts to look at this case.

Comment: Did you know the reason? I had a similar issue @schperplata

Comment: No :( I assume SO might not be the best place to get answer to such questions where such low level of the implementation knowledge is needed - at least based on the fact that there are no responses. Good luck

Comment: The machinism of context switch is different between python 2 and 3,python2 do switch after excuted fixed bytecode and python3 do switch after fixed time interval,see https://youtu.be/4zeHStBowEk?t=11m40s